# Record audio when sound is detected, like "motion" does for video

Tags: linux, audio

For those not familiar with the "motion" project it monitors your camera and when enough motion is detected in the video field of view it records that to a video file. The project website is [here](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) What I'm looking for is something like that but for audio, does anyone know of any Linux apps that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)'s `rec` with the `silence` predicate can mimic this.

Comment: I think this is the second time you've given me a great answer to a question I posted, thanks X2. Taking a look at SoX now.

Comment: @Gekitsuu: then be thankful, and mark the answer as accepted :). That's how this community works.

Comment: @Sunny I just wanted to verify that it did what I needed before I accepted it :P

Comment: The problem is we won't know when the recorded sounds occured, right?

Comment: @unfa: SoX is patient.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed : `rec ~/tmp/sound.wav silence 1 0.1 2%  1 3.0 2% : newfile : restart`
By looping the recording process between silences, will also tell you when the sounds occurred.
see : https://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/comment-page-2/